# CircleCI Workflow cannot find Firebase project: Invalid project selection please verify project 'project' exists and you have access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, circleci

We have a circle workflow that automatically deploys our webapp to production for us whenever we merge to main. However, since updating our firebase-tools to V10.2.1 we get the following message whenever we try to set our env-config to "production".

```js
> node env-config/env-config "production"
```

Under the hood it runs the `firebase use production` command. Which is when the following error is returned

```
Error: Command failed: firebase use production
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'firebase use production',
  stdout: '\n' +
    '\x1B[1m\x1B[31mError:\x1B[39m\x1B[22m Invalid project selection, please verify project \x1B[1mproduction\x1B[22m exists and you have access.\n',
  stderr: ''
}
```

Now here comes the weird part: in the same workflow it also runs `firebase use test` and `firebase use staging` with both work as expected. Outside of the workflow, just manually running `firebase use production` works as expected as well. Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by refreshing the firebase token used by the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue as well and the accepted answer was not clear to me.

To create a new firebase token please use the following command in the firebase CLI

[firebase login:ci](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#general)

I got this answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128207/firebase-cli-authentication-through-token) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192993/how-can-i-get-firebase-deploy-email-or-token-parameters-to-work) stackoverflow thread